# Is it possible to create a Client Server Model using Python on two different Virtual Machines and have them connect to each other?

Tags: python-3.x, networking, server, client, virtual-machine

[Client Server Model source code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iLexY.png)

Hi all, I was wondering if its possible to have a python script which acts as the client on one Virtual Machine and another python script which acts as the Server on a different Virtual Machine and have the Client successfully connect to the Server? Both Virtual Machines have successfully pinged each other (they are running on internal network). Both scripts work if its on the same Virtual Machine but will not work on two separate Virtual Machines. Thank you in advance for all your help and advice.

I have tried looking up this issue but nothing comes up, all examples are done using the same Virtual Machine.

P.S. The image of source code was on the same Virtual Machine.

Comment: I like ZeroMQ (RabbitMQ is maybe newer?) and I like Websockets, but Websockets have better implementation in Node.js as far as I know. Websockets work also over Internet.

Answer (score 0):

so i was able to answer my own question by simply binding the wildcard address("" or '0.0.0.0') in the server code and setting the server's ip address in the client code when connecting). Therefore the code would look like so:

Server code:

serverSocket.bind(('0.0.0.0', port#))

Client code:

clientSocket.connect(('servers ip address', sameport# as server)).

Comment: Which module do you use?

Comment: @qräbnö I only used the socket module for both Client and Server to create a basic pipeline in which the Client and Server can communicate.

Comment: Ah, OK, `import socket` :)